# Rails nested controller - error: No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rspec-rails

Rails 5.2.1
RSpec 3.8

I'm trying to build a REST API with nested controllers. I'm getting an error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"playlists/playlist_items", :format=>:json, :playlist=>60}
```

Here's my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :playlists do
    resources :playlist_items, controller: 'playlists/playlist_items'
  end
  resources :playlist_items
  resources :artists
  resources :tracks
end
```

Here is the output from `rake routes`:

```
                   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
  playlist_playlist_items GET    /playlists/:playlist_id/playlist_items(.:format)                                         playlists/playlist_items#index
                          POST   /playlists/:playlist_id/playlist_items(.:format)                                         playlists/playlist_items#create
   playlist_playlist_item GET    /playlists/:playlist_id/playlist_items/:id(.:format)                                     playlists/playlist_items#show
                          PATCH  /playlists/:playlist_id/playlist_items/:id(.:format)                                     playlists/playlist_items#update
                          PUT    /playlists/:playlist_id/playlist_items/:id(.:format)                                     playlists/playlist_items#update
                          DELETE /playlists/:playlist_id/playlist_items/:id(.:format)                                     playlists/playlist_items#destroy
... etc ...
```

Here is the test that's failing:

```
describe Playlists::PlaylistItemsController do
  describe "GET #index" do
    before do
      @playlist =  create :playlist, { date: '2000-01-01' } 
      get :index, params: { playlist: @playlist.id, format: :json }
    end
    it "returns http success" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
end
```

The error complains that no route matches

```
{:action=>"index", :controller=>"playlists/playlist_items", :format=>:json, :playlist=>60}
```

but as far as I can tell this line from `rake routes` matches exactly:

```
  playlist_playlist_items GET    /playlists/:playlist_id/playlist_items(.:format)                                         playlists/playlist_items#index
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter is called `playlist_id` not `playlist`.

```
describe Playlists::PlaylistItemsController do
  describe "GET #index" do
    before do
      @playlist =  create :playlist, { date: '2000-01-01' } 
      get :index, params: { playlist_id: @playlist.id, format: :json }
    end
    it "returns http success" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
end
```

Note that the controller should return a [401 CREATED](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201) response.

You can also nest resources in a module by adding the `module` option:

```
resources :playlists do
  resources :playlist_items, module: :playlists
end
```

Comment: On a side note - if you're building a new app from scratch don't use controller specs. Go for request specs instead that actually create real http requests to your application. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec